# Iterating over standard in blocks until EOF is read

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix, io, stream

I have two scripts which are connected by Unix pipe.  The first script writes strings to standard out, and these are consumed by the second script.

Consider the following

```
# producer.py
import sys
import time
for x in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write("thing number %d\n"%x)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

and

```
# consumer.py
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

Now, when I run: `python producer.py | python consumer.py`, I expect to see a new line of output each second.  Instead, I wait 10 seconds, and I suddenly see all of the output at once.

Why can't I iterate over `stdin` one-item-at-a-time?  Why do I have to wait until the `producer` gives me an `EOF` before the loop-body starts executing?

Note that I can get to the correct behavior if I change `consumer.py` to:

```
# consumer.py
import sys    
def stream_stdin():
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    while line:
        yield line
        line = sys.stdin.readline()

for line in stream_stdin():
    print line
```

I'm wondering why I have to explicitly build a generator to stream the items of `stdin`.  Why doesn't this implicitly happen?

Answer (score 2):

According to the `python -h` help message:

> **-u** Force  stdin,  stdout  and  stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On    systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and  stderr  in
>   binary  mode.   Note  that there is internal buffering in xread‐
>   lines(), readlines() and file-object  iterators  ("for  line  in
>   sys.stdin")  which  is  not  influenced by this option.  To work
>   around this, **you will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()"  inside
>   a "while 1:" loop.**